# Resource and Content Management in XNA

Tags: c#, resources, xna

I was wondering how XNA manages resources and content. As in, do I have to handle resource management myself or does the contentmanager do that?

For instance, if I try to load an already-loaded resource (say, a `Texture2D`), will the content manager re-load that resource or will it return the loaded resource from memory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content manager keeps the references for every model loaded, and if you try to load a model previously loaded, it will return the reference to the first.

When content manager is disposed, all the models contained are disposed too, so you have not to dispose your model manually.